# CSS - stopping/starting animation of element, but keeping in sync with other elements

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

Something I'm having a struggle with is css animations.

I have eight images, certain ones rotate and the others are greyscale.
When hovering over a rotating image, I want it to finish rotating and stop on its original position (no rotation). But on top of that, when the hover ends I want it to begin rotating once more, but at the same time as the other rotating elements.

Is this possible?

Here's what I have managed so far

```css
.kanto {
  text-align: center;
}

.kanto img {
  width: 37px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.collected {
  animation: rotation 3s infinite linear;
}

.collected:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.uncollected {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="kanto">
  <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: I did't get your que. Plz clarify more

Comment: Add `animation-fill-mode: backwards;`  this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pausing the animation, make it stick to only one loop, that should do the trick, like this (the only catch is that one animation cycle has to be completed, so if you hover in over in the first 3 seconds, the animation will only "pause" when the animation cycle is completed.):

```css
.kanto {
  text-align: center;
}

.kanto img {
  width: 37px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.collected {
  animation: rotation 3s infinite linear;
}

.collected:hover {
  animation: rotation 3s linear !important;
}

.uncollected {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
 
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="kanto">
  <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
</div>
```

If you cannot wait for a full cycle to be completed you can workaround it, by wrapping the images in a div and injecting and `:after` element which will be a still image, like this:

```css
.kanto {
  text-align: center;
}

.kanto img {
  width: 37px;
  margin: 1px;
}
.wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  }
.collected {
  animation: rotation 3s infinite linear;
}

.wrapper:hover .collected {
  animation: rotation 3s linear !important;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.wrapper:hover:after{
    height: 37px;
    margin: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    background-image: url(https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png);
    width: 37px;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-left: -42px;
}
.uncollected {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
 
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="kanto">
 <div class=wrapper>
 <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
 </div>
 <div class=wrapper>
  <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  </div>
  <div class=wrapper>
  <img class="collected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  </div>
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
  <img class="uncollected" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/e/e6/Glacier_Badge.png/50px-Glacier_Badge.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The second one works best for me - as the first code snippet, I only have to wait for one animation loop on the first hover - each subsequent hover it automatically stops! Thanks a bunch!